# Использование переменных, описаных в другом методе [Unity C#]

Tags: c#, unity3d, классы, переменные

Есть код, из которого мне пришлось перенести несколько переменных из-за того, что они в методе `Update`, вызываемом каждый кадр, и они сбрасывались на первоначальное значение, что бы с ними не делали. Логично.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class controller : MonoBehaviour {


public void Start () {
    int thrust = 0; //changeable
    bool boost = false;
    float speed = 0f; //m/s

}

public static void Update () {

    // variable declaration

    int maxspd = 55;  //}
    int boosted = 90; //} m/s^2
    float accel = 13f;//}
    int boostacc = 16;//}

    Vector3 SPD;
    Vector3 TRANSLUP = new Vector3 (0, 0, -1);
    Vector3 TRANSLRIGHT = new Vector3 (0, 1, 0);
    Vector3 ROTUP = new Vector3 (0, 1, 0);
    Vector3 ROTAXIS = new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);

    // thrust changing and boost

    if(Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0){
        Debug.Log(thrust + ", SCR U");
        if(thrust < 10){
            Debug.Log(thrust + ", UP");
            thrust++;
        }
    }if(Input.GetAxis ("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0){
        Debug.Log(thrust + ", SCR D");
        if(thrust > 0){
            Debug.Log(thrust + ", DOWN");
            thrust--;
        }
    }
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(2)){ // 2 = MMB
        boost = true;
    }else{
        boost = false;
    }

    // acceleration and physics

    if(thrust != 0 && speed < maxspd){
        speed += accel * Time.deltaTime;
        SPD = new Vector3 (-speed, 0, 0);
        transform.Translate(SPD);
    }
    if(thrust == 0 && speed > 0 && boost == false){ //assume braking
        speed += 20 * Time.deltaTime;
        SPD = new Vector3 (speed, 0, 0);
        transform.Translate(SPD);
    }

    // translation

    if(Input.GetKey("w")){
        transform.Translate(TRANSLUP);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("a")){
        transform.Translate(-TRANSLRIGHT);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("s")){
        transform.Translate(-TRANSLUP);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("d")){
        transform.Translate(TRANSLRIGHT);
    }

    // controls rotation

    if(Input.GetKey("e")){
        transform.Rotate(ROTAXIS);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("q")){
        transform.Rotate(-ROTAXIS);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("f")){
        transform.Rotate(ROTUP);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey("c")){
        transform.Rotate(-ROTUP);

    }
}
}
```

И вот в чем проблема: я не могу создать переменную в методе `Update` по вышеуказанным причинам, но и не могу их создать в методе `Start`, ведь тогда использование их в методе `Update` станет невозможным. Дико извиняюсь за неточности и такие глупые вопросы, причем возможно, что это дубликат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте начнём с того, что ваш *класс* — это `controller`, а `Start` и `Update` — это *методы*.

Чтобы совместно использовать переменные в нескольких методах одного и того же класса, можно, например, объявить их *полями* класса. Если методы статические, то и поля должны быть статическими, а если методы нестатические, то и поля должны быть такими.

(Да, к статическим полям могут обращаться и нестатические методы, но я думаю, что в вашем случае нужно оба метода `Start` и `Update` сделать либо статическими, либо нестатическими.)

Получаем примерно такой код:

```
int thrust = 0; // общая переменная

public void Start () {
    thrust = 1000;
    bool boost = false;
    float speed = 0f; //m/s
}

public void Update () { // не static
    if (thrust > 500) ...
```

Comment: Заменил "классы" на "методы".Этот способ даст возможность только читать переменные или читать и записывать в них данные?

Comment: @JetFly: И записывать, конечно, тоже.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь нубу.

Comment: @JetFly: Пожалуйста! Быть нубом не стыдно, все были такими. Стыдно не задавать вопросы и не учить нового. Так что вы всё правильно делаете.

Comment: Мне кажется, или это неправильно что я задал больше вопросов чем дал ответов.Может, я неправ, но мне так кажется.Еще раз спасибо.Кстати,я тут понял,что мне явно нужны значения для ускорения и скорости поменьше.Смещаться на 56 единиц/кадр как-то много.

Comment: @JetFly: Ничего страшного, с опытом будет больше ответов, чем вопросов.

Comment: Нашел небольшую проблему наверное связанную с тем что я пишу говнокод.Через время тело останавливается.Я уверен,можно было проще сделать Vector3 переменные.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68592/discussion-between-jetfly-and-vladd).